# Not able to execute rm through shell_exec in php

Tags: php, apache, unix

I have to delete various files on the server using rm.
I tried using:

```
shell_exec(escapeshellarg(escapeshellcmd("rm -f ./io_cache/".$prob_id."/*")))
```

where $prob_id is a number as well as a name of a directory. Commands like ifconfig are working fine. When using the same command with exec it returns error code 127. If I use a variant :

```
exec("rm ".escapeshellarg(escapeshellcmd("-f ./io_cache/".$prob_id."/*")),$out,$ret)
```

Then it returns error code 1. `shell_exec("pwd")` returns `/opt/lampp/htdocs/mat` and the directory io_cache is present in mat.

I also tried doing the job using a python script. When I call python script without system arguments and deleting some random files the script is running fine.But when I am using something like:

```
shell_exec(escapeshellarg(escapeshellcmd('./rem.py ').$prob_id))
```

To pass the directory from where to delete files then also nothing happens. rem.py is in mat.

I am working on Ubuntu and using apache web server

Comment: does apache (or the user that runs php) have rights to do the rm?

Comment: yes. rm is working fine when running on terminal and disable_functions is blank in php.ini

Comment: If you create the file using YOUR username, and give it chmod 755, group and other have no rights for the file. By default, apache runs under apache user and has no rights to the file then. Can you do ls -l on one 'non deletable' file and post the output? What process wrote those io_cache files?

Comment: @Veda I wrote those files manually and the permissions are set to 777 but I also suppose their is issue of owner. Do you know how to give permissions to apache?

Comment: @Veda How to give read and write acess to apache

Comment: Depends on your situation I guess. If the group rights are enough, you can make apache member of the group that writes the files. If group rights are not enough you can use ACL if your OS supports that.